# Add view to a FrameLayout "invisibly"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

I'm setting up a frame layout that has two views - one is an ImageView and the other is a camera preview. Here's the code:

```
public void setUpCamera(){
    //Set cameraView as the camera preview class
    cameraView = new CameraPreview(getApplicationContext());
    //Set imageResult as an image
    imageResult = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

    imageResult.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    //Prime the frame and buttons from the xml file
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    snapPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);

    //Add both camera preview and the snapped picture to the FrameLayout in the xml file 
    frameLayout.addView(imageResult);
    frameLayout.addView(cameraView);

    frameLayout.bringChildToFront(imageResult);
```

Now my question is whether it's possible to add the cameraView "invisibly" to the FrameLayout? It's a small thing, but otherwise when the camera is set up you get a flash of the camera preview mode before the image is brought to the fore by the bringChildToFront method.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you after `setVisibility(View.GONE)` or `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` ?

GONE adjusts your layout as if the View wasn't completely missing, INVISIBLE maintains any spacing.

Comment: Fantastic that's just the method I was looking for. Many thanks!